# Java net url refused connection

Tags: javascript, java, httprequest, aris

I'm working with ARIS tool and I want to make calls(GET, POST...) in ARIS to ARIS API repository!

I have authentication that works when I try it directly in the repository, but I got an error when I debug the code I have in ARIS.

The error: **Error running script: Connection refused: connect.**

I have the following code:

```
var obj = new java.net.URL(url);
var con = obj.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", java.net.USER_AGENT);

var tenant = "";
var name = "";
var password = "";
var key = "";  

var authString = tenant + ":" + name + ":" + password + ":" + key;  

var encoder = new java.lang.String(Base64.encode(authString));

con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic" + encoder);

var responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
var iN = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
var inputLine = new java.lang.String();
var response = new java.lang.StringBuffer();
while((inputLine = iN.readLine()) != null){
    response.append(inputLine);
}
iN.close();
return new java.lang.String(response);
```

Is the problem that I use Basic authentication, but I have tenant and key also or it's something else?

Also, name, password, key and tenant I'm leaving empty for security purposes, but in the original code the values are inserted. Also the url parameter contains the url link that is called directly in the repository.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: A "Connection Refused" exception means that there is something wrong with either URL you are using or the server you are trying to connect to.

Comment: What is the actual HTTP response code?  Try `"Basic " + encodoer`. 
It looks like there is a missing " " (space).  Also, why is javascript tagged?

Comment: I don't receive response code, just this error: Error running script: Connection refused: connect. It's Javascript tagged because the scripting in ARIS is in Javascript